# AWS DynamoDB VS Couchdb, which would be better to use when?

Tags: couchdb, amazon-dynamodb

When would I want to use one over the other?

Reading about both, they sound oddly similar, so I was wondering if someone with a bit of experience in either would have a run down of pros/cons and in which use cases each excel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the pros and cons of DynamoDB with respect to other NoSQL databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925719/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-dynamodb-with-respect-to-other-nosql-databases)

Comment: Please note that the possible duplicate is mostly addressing MongoDB in fact, and both MongoDB and CouchDB are [Document-oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database).

Comment: @SteffenOpel Couch is only mentioned once in that post, and only in passing.  There is not much elaboration on the relationship between couch and dynamo.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this - what I mean is that you are asking a conceptional question about pros/cons and use cases, and any answer would most likely be almost identical regarding CouchDB or MongoDB, insofar both share the characteristics of a _Document-oriented database_ and are quite similar from a distance therefore (in contrast to DynamoDB, which has a different architecture indeed). I have to agree though, that the answers provided there are not really conclusive yet - I still consider submitting my own, but have refrained from doing so due to the expected length so far ;)

Comment: Being "document-oriented" is the least meaningful characteristic when contrasting Couch and Mongo.

Answer (score 6):

I think the top pros of DynamoDB are explained well in the top answer of [What are the pros and cons of DynamoDB with respect to other NoSQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925719/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-dynamodb-with-respect-to-other-nosql-databases):

- Management
- Integration with AWS
- Community/languages

The most notable feature of CouchDB not supported by DynamoDB is the [views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/intro.html) (see [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/why.html) for a high-level description).

Comment: I'd say CouchDB's the biggest feature is actually [easy replication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/replication/intro.html) between different db instances. And not just replicating between instances in different data centers, but also with web browsers using [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com)

Comment: I think the OP is asking for the comparison of DynamoDB vs CouchDB.